# how to transfer C++ number format to C# number format?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

have the flowing C++ code:

```
CString info, info2;
info.Format("%2d", Value[i]);
info2.Format("%4.1f", Value[j]);
```

want to have the equivalent code in C#

how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code ported to C#:

```
String info;
String info2;
info = String.Format("{0,2:D}", Value[i]);
info2 = String.Format("{0,6:0.0}", Value[j]);
```

6 is used for aligning the string 4 digits plus decimal point plus decimal digit.

NOTE take care of the current Culture used, you might get `,` instead of `.` for some Cultures.

Comment: "{0:D2" will create "01" or " 1" if value is 1?

Comment: D2 will be 01. And FYI, @jdehaan, you're missing a closing }

Comment: Oh damned, you're right! Thanks you both (I made the appropriate changes)

Answer (score 1):

```
Value[i].ToString("D");
Value[j].ToString("####.0");
```

Comment: you first statement doesn't specify the minumn 2 digits width. right?